# Proving inequality (with $\ge$) using induction

Tags: induction

> **Prove that for $n\ge 3, 2^{n-1}\ge n+1$.**

I tried to prove it using induction but in the inductive step not sure what to do when I get that $$2\cdot 2^{n-1}\ge n+2$$ From assumption, we have that $2^{n-1}\ge n+1$, but how to use it here?

Comment: Try writing $n+2=(n+1)+1$, and use the bound $1 \leq 2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $2^{n-1}\geq n+1$. This implies
\begin{align*}
2.2^{n-1}&\geq 2(n+1)\\
&=2n+2\\
&> n+2
\end{align*}
as $2n>n$.

This completes the proof.